# Can I use a Coffeescript `switch` block in eco?

Tags: coffeescript, switch-statement, eco

Can I use a Coffeescript `switch` block in the eco templating engine? I tried a couple of variations, but I keep getting `unexpected dedent` errors.

**Update:** To appease the downvoters, here is what I expected to work

```
<% switch x : %>
<% when 1 : %>
    one
<% end %>
<% when 2 : %>
    two
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I get "Parse error on line 5: unexpected dedent"

Comment: with colons at the end and matching <%end%> and without. What pattern should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECO templates don't appear to support the `switch` statement.

The generated CoffeeScript code for your code is:

```
switch x
  __out.push '\n'
  when 1
    __out.push '\n    one\n'
  __out.push '\n'
  when 2
    __out.push '\n    two\n'
  __out.push '\n'
```

The two `__out.push '\n'` lines after `switch x` and the end of the second `when` statement don't seem to allow this CoffeeScript snippet to compile into JavaScript.

Looking through the code, I couldn't figure out how to prevent those lines from being printed. This might be a good bug to report to the guys that make [eco](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco).

Comment: It seems that eco currently does indeed not support `switch`. I file a bug report. https://github.com/sstephenson/eco/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

I'm only somewhat familiar with eco, but it seems as though it would just not be creating the right CS from that expression. Considering CS uses `when x then y`, I'm not sure you're getting that on compile.

You could try this instead:

```
<% switch x : %>
    <% when 1 then: %>
        one
    <% end %>
    <% when 2 then: %>
        two
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```